# Lambda: Uploaded txt file to S3 using Boto3 looks very from local version

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda, boto3

I am reading a csv from an S3 bucket in Lambda using python 3. I am doing a little bit of sanitation and converting it to a TSV txt file. When I check the file that is stored locally by opening the file in python and printing its contents, it is what my I would expect my output to be. But when I look at the file uploaded to S3, the file is wildly large and has really unexpected contents.

I've tried the same code locally (without uploading to S3) and the file looks OK. I have also tried simply writing the data directly into the outfile (without adding date or anything) and it looks Ok on S3. It is when I add a date to the front of each line and upload to S3 that it looks strange.

```
import csv
import boto3
from datetime import date

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = unquote_plus(record['s3']['object']['key'])
        csvfile = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        today=str(date.today())
        infile = today+'_input'
        outfile = today+'_output'
        download_path = '/tmp/{}.csv'.format(infile)
        upload_path = '/tmp/{}.txt'.format(outfile)
        s3_client.download_file(bucket,key,download_path)
        with open(download_path, 'r') as in_f:
            with open (upload_path, 'w') as out_f:
                r = csv.reader(in_f,delimiter=',',quotechar='"')
                w = csv.writer(out_f,delimiter='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                for line in r:
                    line.insert(0,today)
                    print(line)
                    w.writerow(line)

        s3_client.upload_file(upload_path,bucket,'newTSV.txt')
```

EXPECTED LINE in TSV:

```
2019-10-04  U.S. Dollars    HEDGE FUND  MyFund,LLC|23A              1736
```

ACTUAL LINE in TSV:

```
2019-10-04  "2019-10-04 ""2019-10-04    """"2019-10-04  """"""""2019-10-04  """"""""""""""""2019-10-04  """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

Comment: When I try your code, it looks fine. Nothing wrong.

Comment: It looked fine on S3, too? When I run it, the local file is fine, but the uploaded file in my S3 bucket is bizarre.

Comment: Maybe the input is somehow different but the file on s3 looks good in my case.